# Responsive Filtering Image Gallery P

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, responsive

I have been self learning web development over the past couple of months and I have been working on creating a portfolio site for my photography work. I am quite close to achieving what I am looking for, which is a responsive cross device filtering image gallery.
For the most part, it works, except for one issue: It looks good on mobile devices, but not on large screens.

[For illustrative purposes, here is the site, since files are already on hosting server.](http://danielg.co/photography.php.)

As you can see, the site and gallery load fine, with the "Show all" category initially active. Filtering through the categories works too, and on mobile devices the images stack just fine, except on those with width of 500px and above, as in a rotated phone/tablet screen or a maximized window. I have been playing around with different css attributes to get this fixed, but I simply cannot figure this one out.
For you to be able to replicate the issue, the filtering buttons must be pressed, on a large screen device/maximized window.

Here is how the gallery code is set up(I left out what I think is unnecessary, such as php includes/navigation/etc):

```js
    filterSelection("all")

    function filterSelection(c) {
        // console.log("filterSelection function " + c);
        let images, i;
        images = document.getElementsByClassName("img ");
        // console.log(images);
        // console.log(c);
        if (c == "all") {
            c = "";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
            removeClass(images[i], "show");
            if (images[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) {
                addClass(images[i], "show");
            }
        }
    }

    function addClass(element, name) {
        // console.log("addClass function");
        var i, arr1, arr2;
        arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
        // console.log(element);
        arr2 = name.split(" ");
        // console.log(name);
        for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
                // console.log(element.className);
                element.className += " " + arr2[i];
                // console.log(element.className);

            }
        }
    }

    function removeClass(element, name) {
        // console.log("removeClass function");
        var i, arr1, arr2;
        arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
        arr2 = name.split(" ");
        // console.log("arr1" + arr1);
        // console.log("arr2" + arr2);
        for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
            while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
                arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i], 1));
            }
        }
        element.className = arr1.join(" ");
        // console.log("element " + arr1);
    }

    var catButtons = document.getElementById("catButtons");
    var buttons = catButtons.getElementsByClassName("btn-dark");
    // console.log("buttons " + buttons);
    // console.log(buttons);
    // console.log("catButtons " + catButtons);
    // console.log(catButtons);
    for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
        buttons[i].addEventListener("click", function () {
            var current = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-dark active");
            current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            this.className += " active";
            // console.log("current ");
            // console.log(current);
        });
    }
```

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}

h1,
footer {
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

div.gallery img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: #ccc;
}
div .gallery{
    /* float:left; */
    display:grid;
    float:none;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
}

/* .wrapper:after{
    /* content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both; 
} */

div .gallery img:hover {
    border-radius: 15px;
    border-style: inset;
    border-width: medium;
    border-color: #555;
}

div .desc {
    padding: px 10px 10px 0px;
    text-align: right;
    color: white;
}

.vertical-align {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 0px;
}
.vertical-align:after{
    content: "";
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.responsive {
    padding: 0 6px 6px 0;
    float: left;
    width: 24.99999%;
    display: none;
}

/* TODO: divide into 3
@media only screen and (max-width: 750px){
    .responsive{
        width:40%;
        margin: 6px 0;
    }
} */

/* MEDIA QUERIES RESPONSIVE GALLERY */

@media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .responsive {
        width: 50%;
        margin: 6px 0;
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    .responsive {
        width: 99.99999%;
    }
}

/* FANCYBOX THUMBS BOTTOM PLACEMENT */
.fancybox-thumbs {
    top: auto;
    width: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    height: 95px;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.fancybox-show-thumbs .fancybox-inner {
    right: 0;
    bottom: 95px;
}

/* FANCY BOX WATERMARK */

.fancybox-slide.watermark .fancybox-spaceball {
    background-image: url('https://fancyapps.com/GJbkSPU.png');
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* CATTEGORY BUTTONS */
#centerButtons{
    display:block;
    text-align: center;

}

.btn-dark {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #333333;
    border-color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.btn-dark:focus,
.btn-dark:hover,
.btn-dark:active,
.btn-dark.active,
.open .dropdown-toggle.btn-dark {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: black;
    border-color: #444;
}

.show {
    display: block !important;
}

/* !CATEGORY BUTTONS */

/* TMP WORKING  -- FANCYBOX MEDIA QUERY BOTTOM THUMBS */

/* @media all and (min-width: 800px) {
    .fancybox-thumbs {
        top: auto;
        width: auto;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        right : 0;
        height: 95px;
        padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }
      
      .fancybox-show-thumbs .fancybox-inner {
        right: 0;
        bottom: 95px;
      }  
} */
```

```html
<!-- Gallery Wrapper -->
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="vertical-align col-lg-12">
        <div class="responsive img cityscapes">
            <div class="gallery">
                <a href="images/photography/fres/lions_gate.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-type="image" data-width="1280" data-height="854">
                    <img class="" src="images/photography/thumbs/lions_gate.jpg" />
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Description</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="responsive img landscapes">
            <div class="gallery">
                <a href="images/photography/fres/burnaby_mountain.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-type="image" data-width="1280" data-height="854">
                    <img class="" src="images/photography/thumbs/burnaby_mountain.jpg" />
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Description</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="responsive img cityscapes">
            <div class="gallery">
                <a href="images/photography/fres/burrard_bridge.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-type="image" data-width="1280" data-height="854">
                    <img class="" src="images/photography/thumbs/burrard_bridge.jpg" />
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Description</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="responsive img cityscapes">
            <div class="gallery">
                <a href="images/photography/fres/vancity.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-type="image" data-width="1280" data-height="485">
                    <img class="" src="images/photography/thumbs/vancity.jpg" />
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Description</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-align col-lg-12">
        <div class="responsive img cityscapes">
            <div class="gallery">
                <a href="images/photography/fres/vancity.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-type="image" data-width="1280" data-height="485">
                    <img class="" src="images/photography/thumbs/vancity.jpg" />
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Description</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="responsive img landscapes">
            <div class="gallery">
                <a href="images/photography/fres/burnaby_mountain.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-type="image" data-width="1280" data-height="854">
                    <img class="" src="images/photography/thumbs/burnaby_mountain.jpg" />
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Description</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="responsive img cityscapes">
            <div class="gallery">
                <a href="images/photography/fres/burrard_bridge.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-type="image" data-width="1280" data-height="854">
                    <img class="" src="images/photography/thumbs/burrard_bridge.jpg" />
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Description</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="responsive img animals">
            <div class="gallery">
                <a href="images/photography/fres/eagle.jpg" data-fancybox="images" data-type="image" data-width="1280" data-height="823">
                    <img class="" src="images/photography/thumbs/eagle.jpg" />
                </a>
                <div class="desc">Description</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If possible, I would like some advice on how to approach solving this, and if it's possible, given the way I've set up each row to contain 4 photos.

Also, once I get the layout working properly, would like to automate the initial filling of the gallery through a PHP query to the site's DB containing the location and other image details such as the caption and such. I initially had the buttons set up with PHP queries and POST methods, but that was loading the entire category and its respective images again, causing a slower load. With this, I figure it should be a load once, filter after approach. Does this approach sound coherent/efficient, or should I be looking into other alternatives?

Comment: So the problem is that on larger screens, if you filter by say Landscapes, the two photos appear on separate lines, and you would want them to appear beside eachother on the same line?

Comment: @emmzee Thanks for your response, and that is correct. To better visualize it, I think the cityscapes filter illustrates the issue better, where there are blocks in between the divs where the images are meant to be, within the same row. But yes, ideally I'd like them to be next to each other, as you mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have two separate divs with the "col-lg-12" class, one for the first row, and a second for the second row. Each of those divs fills 100% of the viewport. So if you remove some of the inner "responsive img" divs, the remaining images will remain split.

What you can do is put all of your "responsive img" divs in a single containing "col-lg-12" div. If there are more than four, they will get bumped down. This is noted in the docs here, it should work the same even though you're not using Bootstrap columns for the images, same principle applies:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid-example-wrapping

About your second question, whether it's efficient or not can depend on how many photos you're loading. For say a dozen, loading them all at once is reasonable. If you get more than that, you may want to consider loading them a page at a time and setting up some sort of pagination, ex:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#pagination

Either via AJAX to load the images on the fly as you noted, or reloading the page (ex, photography.php?page=2).

Comment: Perfect. Pretty much solves everything I was looking for - very informative links. Thank you very much for the detailed response and help!